# Swift issue using max() and min() sequentially while archiving on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archiving

On "Compiling swift files" step while archiving, it said that a particular file had this error:

```
PHI node has multiple entries for the same basic block with different incoming values!
  %31 = phi i64 [ 3, %385 ], [ %386, %385 ], [ 1, %29 ], !dbg !1370
label %385
i64 3
  %386 = phi i64 [ %23, %27 ], !dbg !1433
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

After commenting the file's code for a while I found out that the following lines of code were the issue:

```
var normalizedStrikes = max(1, strikes)
normalizedStrikes = min(normalizedStrikes, 3)
```

After trying out a lot of things I discovered that I couldn't use max() and then min(), here is what solved the issue for me:

```
var normalizedStrikes = strikes
if (normalizedStrikes <= 0) {
    normalizedStrikes = 1
}
normalizedStrikes = min(normalizedStrikes, 3)
```

Another very nice thing I've found is that if I change the condition to "< 1", it throws the same error. Good stuff.

```
var normalizedStrikes = strikes
if (normalizedStrikes < 1) {
    normalizedStrikes = 1
}
normalizedStrikes = min(normalizedStrikes, 3)
```

My question is: why that happened?

Btw I'm using Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Comment: That's a pretty cool bug.  I duplicated it on my dev environment.  The swift compiler is still fairly new, and is loaded with bugs.  It will improve with time.

Comment: Nice spot with this, I was getting a similar error:

`PHI node has multiple entries for the same basic block with different incoming values!`
`%12 = phi double [ %9, %8 ], [ 1.000000e+00, %8 ], [ 0.000000e+00, %7 ], [ 1.000000e+00, %7 ], !dbg !254`
`label %8`
`double 1.000000e+00`
`%9 = phi double [ %5, %entry ], !dbg !252`
`LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!`

And thanks to your post I found the problem was with:
`progress = min(1, max(0, progress))`

Also I only notice the error occurred while build the Release config which was running Optimisations...

Cheers again!

Comment: Did you file a bug about this?

Comment: Nope, my bad, I was lazy about it, @MatteoPiombo. If you could that, that'd be awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved as of Xcode 6.3 (6D570).